# FB JS SDK can't be fully loaded in browser

Tags: javascript, facebook, http

I have problem with Facebook JS SDK, which I use for some facebook fancy "gadgets". While most of scripts are fully loaded, fb api is not loaded at all (nor after long, long time).
[image]

I'm using this piece of code to do loading:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
     (function (d, s, id) {
                    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                    if (d.getElementById(id))
                        return;
                    js = d.createElement(s);
                    js.id = id;
                    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/pl_PL/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.3";
                    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
                }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

I looked into Google but it looks nobody experienced similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at Facebook's [docs on loading the SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/advanced-setup), I see that one key difference between what Facebook documents and how you are doing this, is that you are appending `#xfbml=1&version=v2.3` to your `js.src`.

Please try to load the SDK exactly like Facebook documents first, in order to make sure that it is not failing due to any modifications you made to the code.